# Eclipse-RCP view not coming on fullscreen

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using RCP 3.x and trying to create a layout which i want full and on the left hand side. I tried many combinations but none seem to work. Here is the screenshot. [image: Error]

and here is the code snippet that i used to create this

```java
public MonitorView(final Composite parent)
    {
        super(parent);
        setDisplayName(I18N("Visual Monitoring of iCommand"));
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        final Composite composite=GUIToolkit.newComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, new GridData(SWT.TOP,SWT.LEFT,false,false,0,0));
        GridLayout layout=new GridLayout();
        composite.setLayout(layout);

        CreatePartControl(parent);

    }

    private void CreatePartControl(Composite parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Composite c =new Composite(parent,SWT.NONE);
        final Canvas canvas=new Canvas(parent,SWT.NONE);
        Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        canvas.setBackground(red);
        c.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override 
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent event)
            {
                int offset_x=130;
                int offset_y=70;
                int j=0,i=0,n=3,x,y;

                DrawRoundedRectangle d= new DrawRoundedRectangle();
                //for loop for column 1.Placing elements column wise. 

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                { x=0;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, j);
                  j++;
                  x=0;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, j);
                  j++;
                }

            j=0;int flag=6;
            //for loop for drawing column 2
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                { 
                  x=offset_x; y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, flag);
                  j++;flag++;
                  x=offset_x;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, flag);
                  flag++;
                  j++;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**Why is the view starting from left and why the canvas is red only from right side .. why the background of rectangles is also not red.**

For added reference. here is the code for drawRoundedRectangle.

```java
void drawrectangle(PaintEvent event, int x,int y,int j)
    {
        event.gc.setForeground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        event.gc.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY)); 
        Font font = new Font(Display.getCurrent(),"Arial",font_size,SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC); 
        event.gc.setFont(font);
        event.gc.drawRoundRectangle(initial_pos_x+x,initial_pos_y+y,width_of_rect,height_of_rect,arc_width,arc_height);
        event.gc.fillRoundRectangle(initial_pos_x+adjust_pos_x+x,initial_pos_y+adjust_pos_y+y,width_of_rect+adjust_width_x,height_of_rect+adjust_height_y,arc_width,arc_height);
        event.gc.drawText(Services_name.get(j), text_x+x,text_y+y);
    }
```

[EDIT] : After changes @greg449 told here is the result.It does not make sense **why the size got smaller when i made the required logical changes**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the parents of your Composite controls wrong so you are ending up with multiple composites side by side.

First:

```java
   final Composite composite=GUIToolkit.newComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, new GridData(SWT.TOP,SWT.LEFT,false,false,0,0));
    GridLayout layout=new GridLayout();
    composite.setLayout(layout);

    CreatePartControl(parent);
```

You are passing `parent` to `CreatePartControl` so you are not using `composite` but it will take up space.

Second:

```java
private void CreatePartControl(Composite parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Composite c =new Composite(parent,SWT.NONE);
    final Canvas canvas=new Canvas(parent,SWT.NONE);
```

You create composite `c` but then use `parent` as the parent for the `Canvas` so `c` and `canvas` are side by side.

You will also need the paint listener to be on the canvas since that is what you want to draw on.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,they were at their logical best but after including you changes i am getting something unexplained.  See the edit in the ques. Thanks again

Comment: You probably have not set enough layouts and layout data on the various controls. Ask a new question with the revised code.

Comment: i solved the problem by using fill Layout. but the view is still coming in the right... any ideas? Should i add a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385501/eclipse-rcp-view-not-coming-on-the-left-side-on-the-screen) I have asked a new question.

Comment: can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675709/no-scroll-on-view-in-eclipse-rcp)