# Eclipse RCP view not coming on the left side on the screen

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

After taking cue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372028/eclipse-rcp-view-not-coming-on-fullscreen) ques. I ended up here but the problem is, view is coming on right hand side of the screen and not occupying the full space. 
Here is the current screenshot .

[image]

and the code is

```java
public class MonitorView extends CoreView 
{
    public MonitorView(final Composite parent)
    {
        super(parent);
        setDisplayName(I18N("Visual Monitoring of iCommand"));
       // setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final Composite composite=GUIToolkit.newComposite(parent, SWT.FILL, new GridData(SWT.TOP,SWT.LEFT,true,true,1,1));
        FillLayout layout=new FillLayout();
        composite.setLayout(layout);
        CreatePartControl(composite);


    }

    private void CreatePartControl(Composite parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Canvas canvas=new Canvas(parent,SWT.NONE);
        Color white = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
        canvas.setBackground(white);
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override 
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent event)
            {
                int offset_x=130;
                int offset_y=70;
                int j=0,i=0,n=3,x,y;

                DrawRoundedRectangle d= new DrawRoundedRectangle();
                //for loop for column 1.Placing elements column wise. 

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                { x=0;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, j);
                  j++;
                  x=0;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, j);
                  j++;
                }

            j=0;int flag=6;
            //for loop for drawing column 2
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                { 
                  x=offset_x; y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, flag);
                  j++;flag++;
                  x=offset_x;y=offset_y*j;
                  d.drawrectangle(event, x, y, flag);
                  flag++;
                  j++;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**How do i bring the view on the left hand side and onto full screen**

**Solution.** See comment thread of question for discussion

```
public MonitorView(final Composite parent)
    {
        super(parent);
        setDisplayName(I18N("Visual Monitoring of iCommand"));
        setLayout(new FillLayout());
        CreatePartControl(this);
   }
```

Rest everything is same for above. Hope it helps :)

Comment: What is `CoreView` and how is this code called from the `ViewPart` `createPartControl`?

Comment: It goes like this CoreView extends CoreComposite extends Composite extends Scrollable extends Control extends Widget. 
and CreatePartControl i am calling from the constructor. It's a function to draw on the View which i have created using my MonitorView Class. It has no relation to Plugin Development.

Comment: Without seeing all the classes involved this is very hard to diagnose. It is unusual to subclass Composite like this.

Comment: @greg-449 i got it. The key was to do setLayout(new FillLayout()) and then do  CreatePartControl(this). and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot greg, i just found out you are quite famous at my workplace. :)

Comment: But why did it work i still don't understand. It will be great if you could shed some light on it.